DistNetworkError when using multiprocessing_context parameter in pytorch dataloader
Because of some special reasons I want to use spawn method to create worker in DataLoader of Pytorch, this is demo:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
import lightning

fabric = lightning.Fabric(devices=[0, 2], num_nodes=1, strategy='ddp')
fabric.launch()

class LinearModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(10, 2)  

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = torch.randn(100, 10)
    y = torch.rand(100, 2)
    dataset = TensorDataset(x, y)
    # crashed because of multiprocessing_context='spawn'
    train_loader = fabric.setup_dataloaders(DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, 
                   num_workers=1, multiprocessing_context='spawn'))
    model = LinearModel()
    crit = nn.MSELoss()
    model, optimizer = fabric.setup(model, optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01))
    for epoch in range(0, 10):
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}')
        for xs, ys in train_loader:
            output = model(xs)
            loss = crit(output, ys)
            fabric.backward(loss)
            optimizer.step()

But it crashed with this error:
# https://pastebin.com/BqA9mjiE
Epoch 0
Epoch 0
……
torch.distributed.DistNetworkError: The server socket has failed to listen on any local network address. 
The server socket has failed to bind to [::]:55733 (errno: 98 - Address already in use). 
The server socket has failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:55733 (errno: 98 - Address already in use).

Port 55733 is listened by training processes before so it will crash.
But I want to know, why port will be bind repeatedly when multiprocessing_context is spawn?
My version of Pytorch is 2.2.2 and fabric's version is 2.4.0.
Hope for your reply.
